# My webview android app doesn't share on social networks

Tags: android, wordpress, webview, elementor

I have a website built with wordpress and elementor. I use elementor social sharing icons. They work correctly if they are visited from a browser like google chrome. However, it doesn't work for me from my android app which is a webview.

At the moment, I only have these errors in the console:

```
E/ACodec: [OMX.android.goldfish.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010 
E/chromium: [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported. 
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(549)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
```

Is there a way that pressing the elementor social share button will allow me to do it from the android webview app?

```
package com.app.nameapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mywebView;

    //Variables para el file uploads
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Este codigo debe colocarse antes del SetContentView, para que ayude a ocultar la barra que tiene el titulo de la app. Pero tambien debemos ir themes.xml y ocultarla con el NoActionBar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Este codigo realiza la funcion para mostrar el sitio web desde la aplicación web.
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());





        mywebView.loadUrl("https://canidaerd.com/");

        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); //Este codigo me ayudo a resolver el problema de que no mostraba los PopUp del sitio web.
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        //Este codigo coloca la app modo full screen, pero no elimina la barra negra con el nombre de la app.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        

//Esta seccion ayuda a que la aplicacion pueda subir archivos como fotos.
        mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {

            // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
            // onActivityResult attached before constructor
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }


            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                }
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }



        });


    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }


    }
//Hasta aqui termina la seccion de codigo que habilita la subida de archivo.



    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    


}
```